# Which package produced this plot with selectable legend text?

Tags: graphics

I would like to produce plots similar to the one show below ([arXiv link to paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.4503.pdf)).

All text in this plot is selectable. I suspect this plot was not done with R or GNU Plot, but TikZ/PGF LaTeX packages because of the selectable text and because it does not look like R or GNU plots.

Can someone tell for sure what packages were used for the plot below? (I guess I could email the authors...)

[image]

Comment: Looks like MATLAB to me.

Comment: Who knows? I'm pretty sure I could reproduce these plots with R if I had access to the data. And "selectable text" just means that these plots are vector graphics.

Comment: Update: they were produced by gnuplot, not LaTeX — downloading the paper’s source files (available from its [main arXiv page](http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.4503) under “other formats”), one can see the original pdfs of the figures, and their metadata says they were created by gnuplot.

Comment: @jakebeal given how squished the text in the legend looks, I agree with MATLAB, PGFPlots would never look that bad.

Comment: Doesn't look like Matlab at all.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine You answered my question, thanks! Not sure how I can accept your comment as answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Answer converted from comment.)

Downloading the paper’s source files (available from its [main arXiv page](http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.4503), under “other formats”), one can see the original pdfs of the figures, and their pdf metadata says that they were created by gnuplot.  Specifically, they list “Content creator: gnuplot 4.2 patchlevel 6” and “PDF Producer: GPL Ghostscript 9.07”.

These are then included in the main LaTeX file with `\includegraphics[scale=0.55]{impact_examples.pdf}`, and so on.

The two 3D figures are supplied as `.png` files, and don’t appear to contain any such revealing metadata.  They have different fonts from the other figures, so I would guess they were created using a different tool.

Answer (score 2):

That is not hard.

You should save your plot into vector format. Not `.png` or `.jpeg`.

If you use Matlab, when you click "save as", you could select the format as `".eps"`. And by doing so you can zoom your plot without blurring it and at the meantime the legend are text rather than an image.

Comment: might be better to save as pdf from Matlab.  One can also convert pdf to svg using pdf2svg. with svg one can also use it for HTML with tex4ht.

Comment: Saving to either pdf or eps from matlab seems to discard any selectable text, at least in 2016b + adobe reader